# Intersection of two lists based on a specific distance (threshold)

Tags: python, performance, intersection

I want to find the values from `list1` that are close enough to the values from `list2` (based on a specified threshold) i.e similar functionality to the code below.
However, the implementation of `intersect_with_threshold()` below is very slow compared to pyhton's `set` intersection (many orders of magnitude slower!)
Unfortunately python's `set` intersection is not helpful for my purpose as I need to use a threshold to choose the intersected values.
Can anyone please guide me on how to speed up `intersect_with_threshold()` function?
Thanks a lot in advance

```
import time
import random

ln=100
list1=[]
list2=[]
#generating the two lists
for i in range(1000):
    list1.append(round(random.random()*ln))
    list2.append(round(random.random()*ln))

# custom intersection function with a threshold    
def intersect_with_theshold(lst1, lst2, threshold):
    intersected_list=[]
    for j in lst1:
        for i in lst2:
            d = abs(i - j)
            if(d < threshold):
                intersected_list.append(j)
    return list(set(intersected_list))  

## using the custom made intersection function    
t1=time.time()
out1=intersect_with_theshold(list1, list2, 0.001)
t2=time.time()
print(t2-t1)    

## using inbuilt python intersection function 
t1=time.time()
out2=(list(set(list1).intersection(list2)))
t2=time.time()
print(t2-t1)
```

Comment: you are iterating over the same list twice `for j in lst2:
        for i in lst2:` Why?

Comment: thanks for letting me know, that was a typo and now I fixed it.

Comment: Try http://toblerity.org/rtree/tutorial.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to avoid comparing each item from one list with each item from the other list.

In this case it helps to sort the lists. I hope the idea is clear from the code. Either one or other index is incremented. (Using `i` for indexing `lst2` and `j` for `lst1` as you did.)

```
def intersect_with_theshold(lst1, lst2, threshold):
    intersected_list=[]
    lst2 = sorted(lst2)
    i = 0
    for j in sorted(lst1):
        lower = j - threshold
        try:
            while not lower < lst2[i]:
                i += 1
        except IndexError:
            break
        if lst2[i] < j + threshold:
            intersected_list.append(j)
    return list(set(intersected_list))
```